# Where should i put config_custom.php after i added custom font kartik yii-mpdf in yii2

Tags: yii2, mpdf, kartik-v

After i create the custom config file for change the font type in mpdf-yii2 where should i put this file and how i can call it.
this is the custom_config.php

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$defaultConfig = (new Mpdf\Config\ConfigVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontDirs = $defaultConfig['fontDir'];

$defaultFontConfig = (new Mpdf\Config\FontVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontData = $defaultFontConfig['fontdata'];

$mpdfConfig = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
        'mode' => 'utf-8',
        'format' => [190, 236],
        'tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/web/css/fonts',
        'fontDir' => array_merge($fontDirs, [
            __DIR__ . 'web/css/fonts/tajawal'
        ]),
        'fontdata' => $fontData + [
                'tajawal' => [
                 'R' => "Tajawal-Regular.ttf",
                'L' => "Tajawal-Light.ttf",
                'B' => "Tajawal-Bold.ttf",
                'useOTL' => 0xFF,
                'useKashida' => 75,
                ],
            ],
        'default_font' => 'tajawal'
]);
```

this is configuration for this library in /config/web.php

```
   'pdf' => [
            'class' => Pdf::classname(),
            'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
            'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
            'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
            'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/src/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
            'cssInline' => '.row { margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; }',
            'methods' => [
                'SetTitle' => 'Title',
            ],
        ],
```

and this code in controller.php

```
 $pdf = Yii::$app->pdf;
        $pdf->methods = [
            'SetTitle' => $pdfTitle ,
        ];

        $mpdf = $pdf->api;
        $mpdf->setAutoBottomMargin = 'pad';

        if($language == 0) {
            $mpdf->SetDirectionality('ltr');
        } else {
            $mpdf->SetDirectionality('rtl');
        }
        $pdf->content = $content;

        return $pdf->render();
```

I am try it this code  added the options

```
      'pdf' => [
            'class' => Pdf::classname(),
            'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
            'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
            'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
            'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/src/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
            // 'marginLeft'=>0,
            // 'marginRight'=>0,
            // 'marginFooter'=>20,
            'cssInline' => '.row { margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; }',
            'methods' => [
                'SetTitle' => 'Title',
      
            ],
            'options' => [
                'config' =>  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/css/fonts/config-fonts.php',
            ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at `kartik\mpdf\Pdf` [class source code](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/blob/6a6506e680e4a07b1781da12bed9c080263f5f4a/src/Pdf.php#L276). It creates its own instance of `Mpdf` object. So creating your own instance in `custom_config.php` won't help you when you work with `Yii::$app->pdf`.

Looking at how `Mpdf` instance is created inside `Pdf` class, whatever is set in its `options` property will be passed into `Mpdf` as constructor parameter after some values being overwritten by `Pdf` component properties. That means that whatever you would pass to `Mpdf` constructor in your `custom_config.php` needs to be set up in `options` property when configuring `Pdf` component.

To keep your `config/web.php` clean you can prepare options in extra file, for example `config/pdf.php`:

```php
$defaultConfig = (new Mpdf\Config\ConfigVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontDirs = $defaultConfig['fontDir'];

$defaultFontConfig = (new Mpdf\Config\FontVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontData = $defaultFontConfig['fontdata'];

return [
    // your font configurations
    'fontDir' => array_merge($fontDirs, [
        dirname(__DIR__) . '/web/css/fonts/tajawal', // the dirname() is used here because __DIR__ points to `config` directory.
    ]),
    'fontdata' => $fontData + [
        'tajawal' => [
            'R' => "Tajawal-Regular.ttf",
            'L' => "Tajawal-Light.ttf",
            'B' => "Tajawal-Bold.ttf",
            'useOTL' => 0xFF,
            'useKashida' => 75,
        ],
    ],
    // keep defaults that are set up in Pdf::$options
    'autoScriptToLang' => true,
    'ignore_invalid_utf8' => true,
    'tabSpaces' => 4,
];
```

As you can see I've left out `mode`, `format`, `tempDir` and `default_font` options, because these are overwritten by `Pdf` component properties so we need to set them there.
You don't need to require `vendor/autoload.php` because that is already included in `web/index.php` file before config is loaded.

Now we need to use this file in your `Pdf` component setting in `config/web.php`.

```php
'pdf' => [
    'class' => Pdf::classname(),
    'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
    'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
    'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
    'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/src/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
    'cssInline' => '.row { margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; }',
    'methods' => [
        'SetTitle' => 'Title',
    ],
    'mode' => Pdf::MODE_UTF8, // we will use constant defined in Pdf class instead of plain text
    'tempPath' => dirname(__DIR__) . '/web/css/fonts', // tempDir uses tempPath property instead. Make sure the path to temp dir matches actual directory structure
    'defaultFont' => 'tajawal',
    'options' => require __DIR__ . '/pdf.php', // here we use the extra file with pdf configuration we've prepared
],
```

This should make sure the `Mpdf` instance in `Pdf` component is created with configuration you've set up.